# My little text game is getting errors, not sure why

Tags: java

This is for my intro to computer science class(First part of the code is formatted weird, can't figure out how to format it on this site), it is getting these two errors. (Again sorry for formatting, tried my best)

C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\shitty java programs\Spookster.java:23: error: 'else' without 'if'
            } else if (actionTwo == 2); {
              ^
C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\shitty java programs\Spookster.java:39: error: 'else' without 'if'
            } else if (actionThree == 2); {
              ^
2 errors

```
import java.util.*;

public class Spookster
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int actionOne, actionTwo, actionThree;

    System.out.println("You wake up in a metallic room. There is a knife next to you, and there is a door ahead of you.");
    System.out.print("Press 1 to go to the door, press 2 to pick up the knife: ");
    actionOne = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (actionOne == 1) {
        System.out.println("You walk to the door. There is a small window that you could look through.");
        System.out.println("You could also just open the door right there.");
        System.out.print("Press 1 to look through the window, press 2 to go through the door: ");
        actionTwo = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (actionTwo == 1); {
            System.out.println("You look through the window and see a tall creature inside a cockpit.");
            System.out.println("Suddenly you are grabbed from behind and everything is black");
            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
        } else if (actionTwo == 2); {
            System.out.println("You open the door and hear something behind you, you shut it fast then are in shock");
            System.out.println("Another creature is staring you down in front of you. He runs at you with a electrical sword");
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to dodge, enter 2 to defend yourself");
        }

    } else if (actionOne == 2) {
        System.out.println("You pick up the knife and hear something behind you.");
        System.out.println("You blindly throw your hand backwards and realise you killed a tall creature.");
        System.out.println("There is an advanced gun in his hand");
        System.out.print("Press 1 to pick up the gun, press 2 to leave it be: ");
        actionThree = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (actionThree == 1); {
            System.out.println("You grab the gun and the creature moves, you quickly aim and fire");

        } else if (actionThree == 2); {
            System.out.println("The creature becomes conscious and aims the gun at you, you stand in fear.");
            System.out.println("Suddenly you hear a loud noise and everything is black.");
            System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You terminate the `if` body (and `else if` body) here

```
if (actionTwo == 1); {
    System.out.println("You look through the window and see a tall creature inside a cockpit.");
    System.out.println("Suddenly you are grabbed from behind and everything is black");
    System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
} else if (actionTwo == 2); {
    System.out.println("You open the door and hear something behind you, you shut it fast then are in shock");
    System.out.println("Another creature is staring you down in front of you. He runs at you with a electrical sword");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to dodge, enter 2 to defend yourself");
}
```

with the semicolons. Remove those like

```
if (actionTwo == 1) {
    System.out.println("You look through the window and see a tall creature inside a cockpit.");
    System.out.println("Suddenly you are grabbed from behind and everything is black");
    System.out.println("YOU ARE DEAD");
} else if (actionTwo == 2) {
    System.out.println("You open the door and hear something behind you, you shut it fast then are in shock");
    System.out.println("Another creature is staring you down in front of you. He runs at you with a electrical sword");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to dodge, enter 2 to defend yourself");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semilcolons after if and else if statements.